# Does using google FCM for business App requires registration fee?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) in my organization's internal App which is not going to be hosted on google play. Does it require any kind of payment? I searched about it, all the searches pointed to google play developer console which charges $25 as one time registration fees. I assume registering on google play developer console is required when we want to host an App on google play. Correct me if I am wrong.

Currently I am able to use FCM in the App just by signing in using my gmail account. I want to know whether payment is necessary for using google FCM service in the App.

Comment: so what is the problem ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya : I want to know whether payment is necessary for using google **FCM** service in the App.

Comment: [Pricing of FCM](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

Comment: @jankigadhiya : Thank You. You solved my query. Just correct me if I am wrong, Google Play developer console account is only required if we are going to host the App on Google Play.

Comment: @jankigadhiya : I am already using FCM without registering on **google play developer console**. I am able to visit [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) using my gmail account. Whereas when I try to access [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) it shows me a payment page. Thus I think registering on **Google Developer Console** is not required for using FCM.

Comment: My meaning was : Without the Google API console the can not use FCM. My misunderstanding. **Yes you will only need Google Developer Console account ONLY if you want to publish your App on play store**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116800/discussion-between-monish-kamble-and-janki-gadhiya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments by @jankigadhiya, FCM service is free of charge, though there are premium packages, as seen in the [Firebase Pricings](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) page.

The $25 registration fee for the Google Play Dev Console is only necessary **IF** you are planning to publish your app via the Google Play Store, as described:

> Google Play Developer Console enables developers to easily publish and distribute their applications directly to users of Android-compatible phones.

Most of the perks/advantage when registering are for apps who's target is the public market. Since you're app is for internal use only, the advantage I think you can make use of should you choose to register for a Google Play Dev Console is [Viewing the App Performance Statistics](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628).

This [How to use the Google Play Dev Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=en) help doc should prove helpful.